# Setup ImGui on Mac with OpenGL 3 and GLFW

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, glfw, imgui

I am new to **OpenGL** and fairly new to C++ as well

I have created an **OpenGL** project on my **intel based Mac** computer using **Xcode**
I am using the following dependencies:

- GLFW
- GLEW
- GLM for the maths

I have set my **OpenGL** and **GLSL** versions as follows:

- OpenGL version: 4.1 ATI-4.2.13
- Supported GLSL version is 4.10

I have downloaded the source files of ImGui from their GitHub page https://github.com/ocornut/imgui
However, I am struggling to link the library and getting undefined symbol compiler errors.

Here is a link to my repository: https://github.com/AybarsAcar/OpenGLScratch

Thank you